# Handling Uninstall for Current User Installation

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, outlook-addin

I have an addin for outlook which is installer per user.The installer copies the dlls and user specific registry entries.I using VS2008 vdproj for generating msi installer.

When two user on a machine install this addin and if one of the user uninstall it, all the dlls will be removed from the ProgramFiles/App directory.

Is there a workaround in installer to Not to remove the dlls if other users also have the app installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to install all of the application to completey per-user locations.